# Pass named arguments to macro

Tags: macros, key-value

I notice that `includegraphics` takes what seems to be named arguments:

```
\includegraphics[width=50,height=25,trim=1 2 3 4,clip]{an_img.png}
```

I'd like to wrap a number of my `includegraphics` calls in a macro, so that the following commands

```
\happygraphics{an_img.png}
\happygraphics{an_img.png}{rotate=90}
```

expand to

```
\includegraphics[width=50,height=25,trim=1 2 3 4,clip]{an_img.png}
\includegraphics[width=50,height=25,trim=1 2 3 4,clip,rotate=90]{an_img.png}
```

respectively.

I've tried using

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\song{ m g }{
  \includegraphics[width=50,height=25,trim=1 2 3 4,clip,rotate=90\IfNoValueF{#2}{,#2}]{#1}
}
```

but I get the dreaded

```
! Package keyval Error: keepaspectratio,trim=0 0 0.5in 0,clip undefined.
```

error.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slightly modified interface via the definition

```
\newcommand{\happygraphics}[2][,]{%
  \includegraphics[width=50,height=25,trim=1 2 3 4,clip,#1]{#2}}%
```

would allow to add options as needed to `\happygraphics[<options>]{<file>}`.

A similar interface is provided through [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

```
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\happygraphics}{O{,} m}{%
  \includegraphics[width=50,height=25,trim=1 2 3 4,clip,#1]{#2}}%
```

The above takes advantage of supplying empty (default) key-values as `,`.

Since the key-value interface is comfortable with supplying empty options (or consecutive commas `,,,...`), there's no need for extra testing of the existence of an optional argument. Unless, of course, you want to do more based on whether or not the use supplied an optional argument.

Comment: How can I know whether the user has elected to use the optional argument? This seems very clear in `DeclareDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @Richard: If the user did not supply the optional argument, then it defaults to `,` (as specified by the second optional argument of `\newcommand`) and it's stored in `#1`. If the user did supply an optional argument, it is still stored in `#1`. So, regardless of whether they supply something or not, `#1` contains that, and is passed to the list of options for `\includegraphics`. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) allows the same interface using the `O{,} m` argument type.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to define a new top level command, if you execute

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=50,height=25,trim=1 2 3 4,clip}
```

then those keys will be automatically set for all `\includegraphics` in the scope of the `\setkeys` declaration.

Comment: Thanks, David. In reality, the code I've shown is part of a much more complex macro of which `\includegraphics` is a part, so I don't think there is a way to get around passing the parameters in the manner I indicated.

Comment: In such cases, I really like ConTeXt's inheritance mechanism. You can define a set of options as `\defineexternalfigure[myoptions][width=50pt, height=25pt]`; for images where you just want to use these options use: `\externalfigure[filename][myoptions]`; for images where you want to use these options with other options as well use: `\externalfigure[filename][myoptions][orientation=90]`. LaTeX assumes that there is one set of default options, which leads to the need to define macros to handle this common use case.